# How do I process a collection of collections asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the past I've had an easy time turning a for loop into a multi-tasking speed demon by using PLINQ.

However, I am having a harder time due to processing a collection of collections.

I will probably figure this out on my own but I thought it would be useful to see how others would solve this as well.

**Update**: I'm convinced there's a conceptual problem with my code below but I've been unable to verbalize it fully.  If anyone can see what I'm talking about, great, but I'll think about this more and try to make the question better overall (or delete it if I realize it's completely my mistake)

Here's main logic:

```
    public static void Execute()
    {
        var service = Locator.Get<ICakeService>();
        using (var db = new Cake.Model.CakeContainer())
        {
            foreach (var campaigns in service.ExportCampaigns())
            {
                // --> THIS LOOP SHOULD BE EXECUTED IN A SEPARATE THREAD
                foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
                {
                    // ... logic to process a campaign ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the service:

```
    public IEnumerable<campaign[]> ExportCampaigns()
    {
        campaign[] result = null;
        var service = new exportSoapClient("exportSoap");
        // --> IF I DO A PARALLEL FOREACH HERE THE CLIENT CODE ABOVE 
        // STOPS MAKING SENSE TO ME...
        foreach (var offer in this.ExportOffers())
        {
            var response = service.Campaigns(
                                api_key: this.apiKey,
                                offer_id: offer.offer_id);
            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i just changed the title

Comment: fixed that too - i think the question is implicit - is something about this question specifically not to your liking?

Comment: Do you have any requirements in terms of order-of-execution or can each campaign (or collection of campaigns) be processed in an arbitrary order?

Comment: no requriements on order - just that all the iterations of the inner for loop complete

Comment: I just think it might be easier on everyone trying to answer your question if they don't have to guess what your problem is.

Comment: ok understood - i'll keep that in mind and improve it if i can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option for parallelization is

```
Parallel.Foreach(service.ExportCampaigns(), campaigns =>
{
    // --> THIS LOOP will be run in multiple threads at the same time


    foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
    {
        // ... logic to process a campaign ...
    }
});
```

If the inner `foreach` has too little of work to do this may be a better option than [esskar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656708/80274).

Here is a version without lambadas

```
public static void Execute(Action<campaign[]> action)
{
    var service = Locator.Get<ICakeService>();
    using (var db = new Cake.Model.CakeContainer())
    {
        Parallel.Foreach(service.ExportCampaigns(), action);
    }
}

//This method will be executed in parallel for each element in the IEnumerable<campaign[]>.
private void ProcessCampaigns(campaign[] campaigns)
{
    foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
    {
        // ... logic to process a campaign ...
    }
}

// Call to Execute looks something like this:
command.Execute(ProcessCampaigns)
```

Comment: and if I wanted I could send in ProcessCampaigns lambda as a parameter to Execute, so `Execute(Action<campaign[]> action)`, right?

Comment: That is correct, and you would just pass in `action` instead of `ProcessCampaigns` to the method.

Comment: yeah that was the point i needed to realize to make it work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) Helper from System.Threading.Task

```
Parallel.Foreach(campaigns, compaign => 
{
    // ... logic to process a campaign ...
});
```

EDIT: here a complete example

```
public static void Execute()
{
    var service = Locator.Get<ICakeService>();
    using (var db = new Cake.Model.CakeContainer())
    {
        foreach (var campaigns in service.ExportCampaigns())
        {
            ProcessCampaigns(campaigns);                
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessCampaigns(IEnumerable<Campaign>> campaigns)
{
    Parallel.Foreach(compaigns, ProcessCampaign);
}

private void ProcessCampaign(Campaign campaign)
{
    // ... logic to process a campaign ...
}
```

Comment: Might need to assign a local instance of "campaign" or "campaigns" here as lambda execution might hit the last/reused values from the foreach loop.

Comment: i don't know where to put that Parallel foreach loop in my posted code... mabye i'm missing something obvious - i'll re-examine it